# alert box appearing more than once?

Tags: jquery, html

html:

```
<div class="box">
   <div><p>Hello World</p></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var count = 0;
  $("#add").click(function(){
    $(".box").append('<div id="'+count+'"><button type="button" class="close">&times;  </button></div>');
    count++;
    $(".close").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    });
  });
});
```

When I click on add the buttons are appended one after the other. When I click the first button of class close with id = 0, the alert box is appearing the number of times buttons are previously added.

I mean if I append 5 buttons and when I press close whose (id = 0) then the alert box is appearing 5 times.

if id = 1 , 4 times
id = 2 , 3 times
id = 3 , 2 times
id = 4, 1 time

If I put the JQuery close click function outside the JQuery add function then the alert box does not appear at all.

How do I get the alert box to appear only once whenever I press any close button?

Hope I explained it in a way others can understand, if not I'm sorry. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need to unbind the close, for example:

```
$('.close').unbind('click');
```

So at your final code this should work fine for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var count = 0;
  $("#add").click(function(){
    $(".box").append('<div id="'+count+'"><button type="button" class="close">& times;  </button></div>);
    count++;
    $('.close').unbind('click'); //<-- This line here
    $(".close").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    });
  });
```

});

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".box").on('click', '.close', function(){
   alert('hi');
});
```

Bind the handler once, rather than every time you append a new button.
Add the above inside the `document.ready` handler.

I'm demonstrating a method of delegating the event handler to an ancestor element, which is in the DOM at the time of initialization.

Comment: This method is more efficient than web-johnny's answer (not trying to cause offense at all). And delegated events are preferred to unbinding and then rebinding handlers... Just for future reference.